# Can't we typecast in C# like below as in python

Tags: c#, variables, casting

I am a newbie and forgive me if this is very basic question.
In python, below is possible.

```
x = 0
x = float(x)
```

Can't we do this in C#? It throws error unless I assign the casting to a different variable

Comment: As a person not familiar with Python, just what exactly are you trying to accomplish? C# is statically typed, and it looks like you're trying to change the type of a variable after declaring it.

Comment: So you can't change the type after declaration in C#?

Comment: `var x = 0;` and `var y = (float)x;`

Comment: _so you can't change the type after declaration in C#_ yup, that's the law

Comment: "Can't we do this in C#? It throws error" Then the compiler already gave you an answer. There is no question to answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in C# when defining a variable, you need to specify the type. For example:

```
int x = 0
```

When you typecast in C#, you need to initialize a new variable of a different type, and set it to the existing variable. To type convert the above line to a float we'd add:

```
float y = x
```

This is called type conversion, it's where the compiler automatically converts the type of a data structure given the context of the code. Type casting is when the programmer specifically specifies the type which he wishes a variable to be converted to. For instance:

```
double x = 3.333;
int y;
y = (int)x;
```

I hope that helped:)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
float f = Convert.ToSingle(i);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can do that

```py
x = 0
x = float(x)
```

in c#

```cs
int x = 0;
float x2 = (float)x;
```

You can't change variable type in c#

Comment: This is not valid C# code, which the question is about.

Comment: Why var x = 0; x = Convert.ToDouble(x); is not possible in C#?